# PHP Using a variable when calling a static method

Tags: php, static, methods

I have three classes that all have a static function called 'create'.
I would like to call the appropriate function dynamically based on the output from a form, but am having a little trouble with  the syntax.  Is there anyway to perform this?

```
$class = $_POST['class'];
$class::create();
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your example throw an error? What is the valid of $_POST['class']?

Comment: It's 5.2.1.
I get the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Comment: For the record, "Paamayim Nekudotayim" is Hebrew for "double colon".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are working with PHP 5.2, you can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) (or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)) :

```
$className = 'A';

call_user_func(array($className, 'method'));

class A {
    public static function method() {
        echo 'Hello, A';
    }
}
```

Will get you :

```
Hello, A
```

The kind of syntax you were using in your question is only possible with PHP >= 5.3 ; see the manual page of [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), about that :

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to
>   reference the class using a variable.
>   The variable's value can not be a
>   keyword (e.g. self, parent and
>   static).

Answer (score 2):

What you have works as of [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

ps. You should consider cleaning the $_POST['class'] since you cannot be sure what will be in it.

Answer (score 1):

use call_user_func

heres an example from php.net

```
class myclass {
    static function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
call_user_func($classname .'::say_hello'); // As of 5.2.3

$myobject = new myclass();

call_user_func(array($myobject, 'say_hello'));
```

Comment: It would be good add this piece of code outside to abstract so much spaguetti.
+1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can only be done since PHP 5.3.0. Check [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and search for `$classname::$my_static` to see the example.

Answer (score -2):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, but how about this?

```
switch ($_POST['ClassType']) {
    case "Class1":
        $class1::create();
        break;
    case "Class2":
        $class2::create();
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

If that doesn't work, you should look into EVAL (dangerous, be careful.)