# PHP - Variable in a static method name

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Using a variable when calling a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626870/php-using-a-variable-when-calling-a-static-method)

I've read through a few different posts on here (I.E. [PHP Using a variable when calling a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626870/php-using-a-variable-when-calling-a-static-method?rq=1)) when trying to use a variable on a static function, but I just can't seem to get the call_user_func_array() function to work the same as if I was able to call the variable directly in the class name.

PHP >= 5.3.0 Method:

```
$data = $factory_model::by_array(array(
    $form_fields['name_field']  => $value
));
```

PHP < 5.3.0 Method:

```
$data = call_user_func_array(array($factory_model, 'by_array'), array(  
    $form_fields['name_field']  => $value
));
```

It's some code that I've inherited so I can't change that much on the models, but it *should* give the following output:

```
initiative_forecast_type Object
(
    [id:initiative_forecast_type:private] => 0
    [forecast_type:initiative_forecast_type:private] => TRTR
    [tstamp] => 2012-06-11 12:52:07
)
```

Which it does using the standard PHP 5.3 Method (My user input/value was 'TRTR')

But if I use the call_user_func_array method I get:

```
initiative_forecast_type Object
(
    [id:initiative_forecast_type:private] => 0
    [forecast_type:initiative_forecast_type:private] => 
    [tstamp] => 2012-06-11 12:52:07
)
```

So it's not setting the 'forecast_type' field. I've uploaded the model here - http://pastebin.ca/2160201

For reference - $factory_model = initiative_forecast_type_factory

I thought the 2 call_user_func_array() function should work the same as the 5.3.0 method, but it doesn't seem to be - Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Christian

Comment: Hmm you should wrap the array in another array when you do call_user_func_array() I think, i.e. the second argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call_user_func_array()` expects the second parameter to be an array of the actual arguments for the function (the keys in the array would be disregarded). What you actually want is `call_user_func()`.

```
call_user_func_array('func', array('foo' => 'bar')) === func('bar')
call_user_func_array('func', array(array('foo' => 'bar'))) === func(array('foo' => 'bar'))
call_user_func('func', array('foo' => 'bar')) === func(array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

Comment: Ahhhh… That's the one… call_user_func with the same parameters worked perfectly - Thanks!